# How to place shapes using SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am learning about layout using SwiftUI and would like to understand how to tell swift that, if there is a background rectangle in a zstack, and a series of smaller shapes on top, to use the rectangle as the reference space. Although when try it seems to space objects over the entire screen (rather than using the the background object). Here is an example of what I am trying to write:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.overlay(alignment:content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/overlay(alignment:content:)) to place a subview relative to the parent view.

For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.blue
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .overlay(alignment: .center) {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    HStack(spacing: 2) {
                        ForEach([Color.yellow, .red, .white, .green, .cyan], id: \.self) { color in
                            Circle()
                                .foregroundColor(color)
                                .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

---

Here it is running in the simulator:

[image: image running in a simulator]